# Bing search extension (Google-like)

Tags: google, bing

Is there in Bing (www.bing.com) anythink like Google searching extensions?

**For example**:

```
inurl:bing site:stackoverflow.com
```

will restrict searching through Google only for this (awesome, btw) website and only for pages containing word *bing* in url address.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/19164/does-bing-have-advanced-search-operators

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the comment, if you go on [this Bing help page](https://help.bing.microsoft.com/#apex/18/en-US/10001/-1), you will find a list of advanced search operators.

They are:

- `contains:`
- `filetype:`
- `inanchor:`
- `inbody:`
- `intitle:`
- `ip:`
- `language:`
- `loc:` (or `location:`)
- `prefer:`
- `site:`
- `feed:`
- `hasfeed:`
- `url:`

Please note that:

> Some features and functionality described here may not be available in your country or region.

<sub>**Disclaimer:** As the user that commented on the post doesn't have his/her account linked to webapps.se, I took the liberty to add the answer with the sole purpose of having a clear answer.</sub>